# How come my code will work in all IE version but not on IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

As the title says. i really can't figure out what is wrong in this.
the `#main` div goes down if it's content is overlapping it's width.

this is the html file with the css style in it:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #header,
      #main,
      #sidebar,
      #footer {
        display:inline;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        background-color:#eee;
      }
      #header,
      #footer {
        width:100%;
        height:60px;
      }
      #header {
        margin-bottom:2%;
      }
      #footer {
        margin-top:2%;
      }
      #main {
        width:68%;
        height:50%;
        margin-right:2%;
      }
      #sidebar {
        width:30%;
        height:50%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">Header </div>
    <div id="main"> content goes here.</div>
    <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

tried on IETester software all versions worked but IE7. It doesn't load anything.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you floating these divs?

Comment: so that `#main` and `#sidebar` would pile up in one line.

Comment: its look same in in all IE version. I am using IE Tester software

Comment: on my IE tester IE7 won't load anything. and if i test it manually on a virtual machine that has IE7 results are different

Comment: @ejay_francisco same in all version of IE.

Comment: even when you fill the `#main` with lots of text?